# image not show in uiimageview

Tags: swift, swift3, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

i want to get image from library but, image not show until I choose from library

this is my code

```
@IBAction func btnProfile(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Change Profil Image", message: "Pilih Foto", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Gunakan Kamera", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            print("Gunakan Kamera")
            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera){
                let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
                imagePicker.delegate = self
                imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera;
                imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
                self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ambil Foto dari Galery", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            print("Ambil Foto dari Galery")
            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary){
                let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
                imagePicker.delegate = self
                imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary;
                imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
                self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            print("Cancel")
        }))
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    guard let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else { return } // error in here >> 'UIImage?' is not convertible to 'UIImage' >> and warning yellow >> Cast from 'Slice<Dictionary<UIImagePickerController.InfoKey, Any>>' (aka 'Slice<Dictionary<NSString, Any>>') to unrelated type 'UIImage' always fails

    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    imgProf.image = image
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I want to display the image on UIimageview, but after I retrieve it from the library it doesn't always appear, 
error in guard let image, and warning yellow in there
i use swift 3

this is UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

```
public protocol UIImagePickerControllerDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {


    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    optional public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])

    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    optional public func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController)
}
```

Comment: @Kamran , i already update

Comment: So you are using Swift 4.2? What is the Xcode version?

Comment: swift 4 , but i use xcode Version 10.0

Comment: For that you can try `info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage.rawValue]` instead of `info[.originalImage]`

Comment: i have error again >> Type 'UIImagePickerController.InfoKey' (aka 'NSString') has no member 'originalImage'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this code and it worked

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        var selectedImageFromPicker: UIImage?
        if let editedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
            selectedImageFromPicker = editedImage
        } else if let originalImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            selectedImageFromPicker = originalImage
        }

        if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker {
            imgProf.image = selectedImage
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

and thanks for @Kamran, your answer for change the position is true

Answer (score 0):

```
self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: {
    imagePicker.delegate = self
})
```

Set picker delegate in completion.